# C# "Controls" Does Not Exist in The Current Context

Tags: c#, wpf

## Error

In my application I'm trying to use "Controls.Add", but Visual Studio keeps giving me the error:

**"Error   1   The name 'Controls' does not exist in the current context
    C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Demo\Demo\MainWindow.xaml.cs 42  13  Demo"**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 window = new Window1();
            Button button = new Button();

            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            button.Content = "New Button";
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            button.Height = 50;
            button.Width = 200;


            Controls.add(button); <-- ERROR IS FOUND HERE


            window.Show();


        }
    }
}
```

I'm using WPF, coming from WinForms. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: button.Name = "button"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something along the lines of:

```
var window = new Window1();

var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };

Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "New Button";
button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
button.Height = 50;
button.Width = 200;

stackPanel.Children.Add(button);

window.Content = stackPanel;
window.Show();
```

Although, I'd recommend defining all UI components in the XAML and reading up on the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <StackPanel Name=“splMain“>
<Button Name=“btnAddMore“ Click=“btnAddMore_Click“>Add Another</Button>
```

Also on button click :

```
System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
  newBtn.Content = “A New Button”;
  splMain.Children.Add(newBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button SaveButton = new Button();
 SaveButton.Name = "Save";
 SaveButton.Content = "Save";
 Grid1.Children.Add(SaveButton);
```